# Disabling kendo datepicker when clicked on checkbox

Tags: kendo-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two kendo date picker in input boxes and one checkbox I want to show the kendo datepickers all the time with current date  . but they become enable /selectable /editable ONLY when user has checked the checkbox.

Checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="RequredFilter" />
```

2 kendo Datepickers.

```
<input type="text" id="DateFrom" />
<input type="text" id="DateTo" />
```

I have tried various things like disabling text-boxes etc but datepickers just keep working/showing..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is special method for enabling/disabling the DatePicker called **enable** - check [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/api.html) demo.

```
$('#RequredFilter').click(function(e){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#DateFrom').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(true);
        $('#DateTo').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(true);
    }
    else{
        $('#DateFrom').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(false);
        $('#DateTo').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(false);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#RequredFilter").change(function() {
        $('#DateFrom').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(this.checked);
        $('#DateTo').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(this.checked);
    });
});
```