# Manipulating datePicker CSS on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, datepicker, kendo-ui

I am trying to enable/disable date pickers depending on other widgets (checkboxes and numeric text boxes). When I try to call DatePicker.enable() with true or false as a parameter, i get an error because the DatePicker isn't ready yet. Seems like Kendo widgets aren't ready until  $(document).ready too. Are there any events or something that would tell me when the date picker is ready to be manipulated ? For now I am using a setTimeout which feels really wrong.

Here is a sample of my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    ChangeDatePickersState();
});

function ChangeDatePickersState() {
    var input = $('#MyCheckbox:checked')
    var bool = input.length != 0 ? true : false;
    EnableDatePickerForCheckbox('MyDatePicker', bool);

function EnableDatePickerForCheckbox(inputName, inputValue) {
    var datePicker = $('#' + inputName).data("kendoDatePicker");
    if (inputValue == true) {
        datePicker.enable(true);
    }
    else {
        datePicker.enable(false);
        datePicker.value(null);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention im using Kendo with MVC, but anyway I got an answer from their forum:

The Kendo UI widgets do not fire events when they are initialized, but you can count on their existence if you include your custom logic inside a document.ready handler, which is added at the end of the page <body>. This will ensure that the handler will be executed after all widget initialization statements, which also depend on document.ready. No setTimeout will be required in this case.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to mention im using Kendo with MVC, but anyway I got an answer from their forum:

The Kendo UI widgets do not fire events when they are initialized, but you can count on their existence if you include your custom logic inside a document.ready handler, which is added at the end of the page . This will ensure that the handler will be executed after all widget initialization statements, which also depend on document.ready. No setTimeout will be required in this case.

Some widgets such as the Grid or the ListView can be initialized, but still not populated in document.ready. Depending on the exact scenario, you can use the corresponding widget's dataBound event to execute custom logic.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker should be ready to modify as soon as you call

```
$("#MyDatePicker").kendoDatePicker();
```

I made the following change in the JS code that you posted here and it worked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MyDatePicker").kendoDatePicker();
    ChangeDatePickersState();
});
```

Refer to these links for more info
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/api.html
[Disabling kendo datepicker when clicked on checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338132/disabling-kendo-datepicker-when-clicked-on-checkbox)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using MVC and my script was before the html helper that created the datepicker, which was the problem.